# How to test assm guard error with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3, aasm

I have a state machine with some guards to prevent special state transitions.
In my spec, I'm trying to expect guard violation error like this:

```
expect(violate_guard).to raise_exception
```

As a result, I receive correct error in my spec test:

> Failure/Error: expect(my_model.change_event).to raise_exception
>        AASM::InvalidTransition:
>          Event 'change_event' cannot transition from 'current_state'

I'm wondering how should I change my spec to have a satisfied test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try:

```
expect { violate_guard }.to raise_error
```

http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/frames

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand well.
If you want a method to wrap the transition violation, you must define a method in the spec

```
def violate_guard
  job = Job.new
  job.run ## <= invalid transition
end
```

then you use the method in spec

```
expect { violate_guard }.to raise_error
```

Comment: Awesome! Your answer was not the answer, however your syntax mistype opened my eyes! `expect { violate_guard )` open brace and closing parenthesis! I should use `{}` to pass a method to `expect`